# how loop through multiple checkbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

I have 100 checkboxes in a winform.
Their names are sequential like `checkbox1`, `checkbox2` etc.
I have a submit button in my winform. After clicking the submitting button, it checks, if a checkbox is checked then some value is updated otherwise another value is updated.
I have to check 100 checkbox.
So i have to loop through the 100 checkbox to check if the checkbox is checked or not.

I know how to check the checkbox

```
private void sumit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (checkbox1.Checked)
     { 
        //  update 
     }
     else
     {  
        // update another  
     }

     if (checkbox2.Checked)
     {  
        //  update    
     }
     else
     {   
        // update another  
     }

     ......................and so on

}
```

But how can i do this for 100 checkbox???

Comment: Foreach control c in form.controls. Then if c is CheckBox

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih-Do you have all checkboxes inside a container?

Comment: you may consider a datagrid control instead in which you will have a checkbox column and some other invisible column to hold the common logic for each checkbox. Then you can iterate through the rows of the datagrid.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the data to be updated and the checkbox, or can you creat an relationship?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls) // I guess this is your form
            {
                if (control is CheckBox)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)control).Checked)
                    {
                        //update
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //update another
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (var ctrl in panel.Controls) {
    if (ctrl is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)ctrl).IsChecked) {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it. What did you mean with "Do you have all checkboxes inside a container?"?

Comment: inside a container means a panel or a group box ?

Comment: Correct, but `as` + null check is better than `is` + cast (because you only have to cast once).  Even better would be `Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()`

Comment: But why do ask that me?

Comment: Note that this is C# .NET 4 code and not compatible with older .NET

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var box in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (box.Checked)
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i get the checkbox number to use inside the if clause. @Joel Coehoorn

Comment: @DarkenShooter You don't need it. You have a direct reference to the checkbox. If you do need that number, you're doing something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 2):

There is LINQ method `OfType`. Why not use it to get rid of manual type testing and casting?

```
foreach (var ctrl in panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Someone did bring it up actually :)

Comment: Oops... didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach (Control childc in Page.Controls)
    {

            if (childc is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)childc;
                //do your operation

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the write answer for this................

c#

```
           string movie="";
           if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                movie=movie+checkBox1.Text + ",";
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                movie=movie+checkBox2.Text + ",";
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
            {
                movie=movie+checkBox3.Text + ",";
            }

            if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                movie = movie + checkBox4.Text + ",";
            }
            if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
            {
                movie = movie + checkBox5.Text + ",";
            }
            if (checkBox6.Checked == true)
            {
                movie = movie + checkBox6.Text + ",";
            }
          row["EnquiryFor"] = movie.ToString();
```

where row is a object of DataRow and EnquiryFor is the name of sql table column....